# List of Slaves connected to master - Hudson

Tags: hudson, jenkins, slave

Is there a way to find it programatically? I need this as part of an automated run; So this would be very helpful if there is an existing remote API call which can give this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need to parse the HTML - most of the Hudson pages can be turned into API calls by adding URL suffix, e.g. make GET calls to:

http://hudson:8080/computer/api/json

Switch the JSON for either XML or Python if you prefer these over JSON.

If you use just the API suffix, you'll get a short generic help page on the API.

Comment: Good, `+1`! I thought there was something like this, but never got around searching for it.

Comment: 1 Was looking for something like that. But under terms like "jenkins environmental variables" but with no luck.

Answer (score 8):

Groovy script to get all computers:

```
def jenkins = Jenkins.instance
def computers = jenkins.computers

computers.each{ 
  println "${it.displayName} ${it.hostName}"
}
```

Comment: looks nice! 
but where to get info what is "Jenkins" and why there is "instance"?
Isn't it possible to write just: `Jenkins.instance.computers.each{println "${it.displayName} ${it.hostName}"}` ?

Comment: yes, you can write that. it's a matter of taste / coding style.

Answer (score 4):

Look at `http://hudson:8080/computer/`

Comment: Thanks. I saw that. I can parse it and get it as part of my automated run. But wanted to know if there is more specific API for this.

Comment: @Aviator: Look at [openjey's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202270/list-of-slaves-connected-to-master-hudson/3303637#3303637). I kept this open in a browser windows because I seemed to remember that there is an API, but never got around digging for that info. Now openjey has answered that.

Comment: Where is the link in the UI to this? How was I suppose to know this