# Jenkins groovy plugin file not found exception

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I've a script to find the all idle slaves and create a text file using Jenkins system groovy. I'm able to create a empty file and find all idle slaves where as coming to append to the file "idle_slaves.list" i got **java.io.FileNotFoundException** exception. Can somebody help me on this?

```
import jenkins.*
import hudson.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

jenkins = jenkins.model.Jenkins

File file1 = new File(build.workspace.toString() + "/idle_slaves.list")

if(build.workspace.isRemote())
{
    channel = build.workspace.channel;
    fp = new FilePath(channel, build.workspace.toString() + "/idle_slaves.list")
} else {
    fp = new FilePath(new File(build.workspace.toString() + "/idle_slaves.list"))
}

if(fp != null)
{
    fp.write("", null); //writing to file
} 

for (node in Jenkins.instance.nodes) {
  computer = node.toComputer()
  if (computer.getChannel() == null) {
    continue
  }
if (computer.isIdle()) {
 slave = node.name.toString()
file1.append( slave )
}
}
```

Jenkins 2.46

groovy 2.0

[image]

Comment: That means that file not found. Or probably no access.

Comment: Line of error? Can you share your stack trace ? Also what is your requirement, maybe there are another approaches.

Comment: I want to find idle slaves and run a job on each one.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the file itself is not created yet :)

```
File file1 = new File(build.workspace.toString() + "/idle_slaves.list")
```

just creates a pointer to the path if you want to create the file, then add the following line

```
file1.createNewFile()
```

Also ensure the file that you create has permission access, otherwise you will get permission denied.

You add the following piece of code to confirm.

```
// check if the file exists
        boolean exists = file.exists();
        if(exists == true)
        {
            // printing the permissions associated with the file
            println "Executable: " + file.canExecute();
            println "Readable: " + file.canRead();
            println "Writable: "+ file.canWrite();
        }
        else
        {
            println "File not found.";
        }
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually read, why not use jenkins/hudson libraries :

**https://serverfault.com/a/889954**

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'slave'}
    stages {
        ...
    }
}
```

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/43111789/3957754**

```
def jenkins = Jenkins.instance
def computers = jenkins.computers

computers.each{ 
  println "${it.displayName} ${it.hostName}"
}
```

**https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/disableSlaveNodeStartsWith.groovy**

**https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Display+Information+About+Nodes**

```
for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
```